# Single word for generic human "body parts"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that can be used to indicate generic human (or animal) body parts?  Just using the word "parts" without context sounds mechanical and inorganic. Ideally, the word would delineate between mechanical and organic "parts" without additional context; additionally, the word should be all inclusive (i.e. organs doesn't work because it only indicates internal body parts).

Some example sentences to illustrate how the word might be used:
 - In the near future, we may be able to print *organic body parts* 
 - *Body parts* were blown everywhere by the explosion.
 - The cyborgs were in various states of disrepair, with *organic body parts* lying everywhere.

Comment: "Body parts" does it for me because it includes limbs and organs and even eye balls - everything except blood and other fluids which aren't really body parts as much as body ingredients. :-)

Comment: body-part. (hyphenated)

Comment: In this context, you might get away with a substantive *bionics*, a neologism : *biotics*,  or some other *bio-* construction.

Comment: I would say "meat", only I suppose that doesn't include bones.

Comment: “Organs” technically denotes all organs of the body, not just the internal organs. For example, the skin is an organ, as are the eyes. But the connotation is of the internal organs only.

Comment: Viscera might be a good word, but I think it only includes organs.

Answer (score 4):

Body parts in general are the *`members`* of the body. Parts which are distant from the torso are *`extremities`*. For example,

> In the near future, we may be able to print the *members of the body*.

and

> The cyborgs were in various states of disrepair, with *mechanical
>   extremities* lying everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The word ***tissue*** is the technical term for organic body parts, and covers all parts, from eyes to bones; and it can include blood.

> Any of the distinct types of material of which animals or plants are made, consisting of specialized cells and their products:
>   *inflammation is a reaction of living tissue to infection or injury*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tissue)

> 5. *Biol.* The substance, structure, or texture of which an animal or plant body, or any part or organ of it, is composed; esp. any one of the various structures, each consisting of an aggregation of similar cells or modifications of cells, which make up the organism.
>
>    **a.** in animals.
>      The chief forms of tissue in the higher animals are the *epithelial* (incl. *glandular*), *connective* (incl. *cartilaginous* and *osseous*), *muscular,* and nervous tissues. (The term is sometimes extended to include the *blood* as a ‘fluid tissue’.)
>
> [OED]

*Tissue* does not include inorganic cyborg parts as these are not cellular.

Comment: Hmm… I would say _tissue_ is the technical term for what organic parts are **made** of. A leg is a body part, but it is not a tissue—at least not unless _tissue_ has some very technical usage that I’m completely unaware of. _Tissue_ sounds quite odd to me in the example sentences given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Anatomy**

[Dictionary Definition: 

#6  Informal. the human body.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anatomy)

I'm assuming it could also reference animal bodies as well.

Although, I'm somewhat uncertain if the following sentences use the word correctly.

> In the near future we may be able to print *anatomy*. 
>   *Anatomy* was blown everywhere by the explosion. 
>   The cyborgs were in various states of disrepair, with *anatomy* strewn about everywhere.

For the first sentence, it seems like a more correct way to say it would still use two words:

> In the near future we may be able to print *anatomical tissue*.

*Credit to Andrew Leach and Good A.M. for providing direction to my searching.*

Comment: _Anatomy_ is the entire structure of a body or organism, or the entire body/organism itself seen as an entire, connected structure. All three of your example sentences sound **extremely** odd to me with _anatomy_, particularly the first one, which makes so little sense I would have no idea what it was trying to say. In the latter two, you could say, “Pieces of [his/her/their] anatomy were blown everywhere” and “with pieces of their anatomy strewn about everywhere”.

Comment: I agree, the first on does sound odd; however, anatomy doesn't always refer to the entire organism.  You can have anatomy of the hand, anatomy of the eye, etc.  Thus, I was hoping that informally, the word could be used to describe body parts in general.  Perhaps, my hopes are in vain.  :(

Comment: Yes, that's the first sense: the structure of an organism (or part of it). That sense doesn't refer to the organism itself, though, just its structure—when referring to the organism itself, _anatomy_ does refer to the entirety of the organism (seen as a structure).